# I feel like I'm Reinventing XAML. Is there a better way?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project (mine) => biz layer (mine) => core layer (that I can't change)

My MVC screen is generically generated via reflection. It just gets the fields on the model class and loops and draws the control for each field. But only if the field is marked with a `CategoryAttribute` to indicate which tab it's going to be on.

[image]

When I needed fields that come from the core layer to be included in my screen, I couldn't add attributes to those to mark their inclusion (because that code is sort-of off-limits), so I invented this:

```
<view typeName="Policy">
  <!--<category name="Agent">
    <field name="mobjAgent">
      <field name="Code" description="Agent Code" />
      <field name="Name" description="Agent" />
      <field name="ContactName" description="Agency" />
      <field name="Address" />
    </field>
  </category>-->
  <category name="Insured Info">
    <field name="mobjCLClient">
      <field name="IdentificationCode" description="Client Id" />
      <field name="CompanyName" description="Name" />
      <field name="Address" />
    </field>
  </category>
</view>
```

It works but I feel like I'm not taking advantage of some .NET framework that's available to me of which I'm unaware.

I know the razor for this would not have been that much more lengthy, but I only have one generic view that handles every class with reflection. I'm so lazy about getting down and dirty and coding each field individually like everyone else on the earth does. How can this be done in a built in way?

Comment: everybody on earth does it the way you do not like so why are you asking for their opinion ;)

Comment: @CodingYoshi, because there may be a better way that they know about, even if they don't do it. :P